# conda build does not test python imports

Tags: python, conda-build

I am building a python conda package using the meta.yaml below. As far as I understand it should instruct conda build to install the package in a test env and test the listed imports.

However conda build just return with "*Nothing to test for: /tmp/cbuild/linux-64/qats-2.11.24-py36_gf6cd119.tar.bz2*". From what I see there are no traces of conda build creating a test env or trying to import the package.

FYI the test is run on a linux agent.

**Have anyone had similar experience? If so, how did you manage to fix it?**

## Package meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: qats
  version: {{ GIT_DESCRIBE_TAG }}.{{ GIT_DESCRIBE_NUMBER }}

source:
  git_url: .

  git_tag:

build:
  number: {{ GIT_DESCRIBE_NUMBER }}
  string: py{{ CONDA_PY }}_{{ GIT_DESCRIBE_HASH }}
  script: python setup.py install
  include_recipe: False

  entry_points:
    - qats-gui = qats.app.main:launch_from_console # [not unix]

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - setuptools_scm
  run:
    - python
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - scipy
    - h5py
    - hdf5
    - qt >=5.6.0
    - pyqt >=5.6.0

test:
  imports:
    - qats
    - qats.TimeSeries
    - qats.TsDB

  commands:
    - qats-gui -h # [not unix]

about:
  home: https://my.visualstudio.com/qats
  license: MIT
  license_file: LICENSE
  summary: Tools for working with time series and various time series file formats.
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the git repo for this code so we can test out the recipe?

Comment: Which conda-build and conda versions are you using? I have similar problems on Windows with 4.3.27 and conda-build 3.0.19.

Comment: I do not have a link currently as I am hosting this in VSTS on a company account. I use miniconda 3 version 4.3.27.1 for linux. And conda build 3.0.27. I have had the same issue with previous versions of conda build. The strange thing is that, the test command `python -m unittest discover -s "test*"`